# Can "the fact that X" imply "X is a fact"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, expression-choice

> **A**: How do I know if  my professor is good?
>
> **B**: Do you understand what he says?
>
> **A**: Yes, but that might be because I'm a natural genius, and not
>   necessarily the fact that he is good at teaching.
>
> **B**: Oh, you said *"the fact that he is good at teaching"* - so you are
>   already taking for granted that he is a good professor!
>
> **A**: You're an idiot.

This scenario was just made up - this never actually happened to me. However, I thought it is possible nonetheless (very rare though).

**Can** saying *"the fact that X"* imply *"X is a fact"*? What could **A** say instead to *prevent* **B** from using that logic?

Comment: A can prevent B from using that logic by preemptively saying, “Oh, I'm an idiot, I forgot he's good at teaching.”

Comment: The usage of *fact* in the context is incorrect, inappropriate and unwarranted. Use *fact* to state what you believe is true. Say '* ... not necessarily that ...*'. ("You're an idiot." is unwarranted and inappropriate, as well.)

Comment: This is really a logic question, and not so much about English Language and Usage.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as off-topic...seems pretty clearly like a valid usage question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Speaker A is listing the possibilities. He is not stating that the professor is good at teaching or that A is a genius.

He is saying that one of these two options is likely. In fact he is implying that these are the only two options.

Comment: I'd agree, if A had said  “not necessarily that he is good at teaching”, but “not necessarily the fact that he is good at teaching” is stronger than “just a possibility”.

Comment: No. Using _the fact that_ instead of simply _that_ presupposes the _that_-clause. What it has to mean is _that it's not **simply** the fact that he's good at teaching_; i.e, there are other factors.

Comment: I'd say that speaker A's intention is clear but his wording is poor. "the fact that" should *definitely* be replaced with "because," which would correct the questionable syntax of the sentence as well as clarify the meaning.